# Trying to invoke a method using delegates after user types in method name

Tags: c#, delegates

Beginner here. I'm trying to call a method in c# depending on the user input: For instance;

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter input:");
    string cmd = Console.ReadLine();
```

user types in: Method1 or Method2 and then that method is called.

I do not what to use  conditional statements or case switching; I'm trying to do this with delegates.

This is what I started with:

```
public delegate void RunComm(string arg1, string arg2); 

Console.WriteLine("Enter input:");
string cmd = Console.ReadLine();

RunComm runthis = RunComm(cmd);

public static void Method1(){

//Run Code
}

public static void Method2(){

//Run Code
}
```

I am trying to do the above and I need it to work in a similar fashion as above, but after reading and watching tutorials online I am finding that the above doesn't work.

Does anyone know why? If delegates are not the answer here, does anyone know what is? Any sample code you can share?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, Action>` or reflection.

Comment: You can't create a delegate from a string. `new RunComm` accepts a delegate or a method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for the reflection API (found in the [`System.Reflection` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx)).

1. Take the containing `Type`.
2. Find the `MethodInfo` of the method that matches your criteria (in this case, only the name). Make sure you specify the correct [binding flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) (and combine them with the `|` operator).
3. [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) the method. If it's a static method, you invoke on a `null` reference.

Example:

```
typeof(Container)
    .GetMethod(cmd, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```